# jqGrid - malfunctions in the grid behavior after using the 4.7.1 columnchooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I like jqGrid and enjoy it's powerful API.  There seems to be a series of issues with the ColumnChooser plugin that I can't overcome.

**The following issue are observed DURING using of the ColumnChooser:**

1. The scroll on the right is appeared on the entire window, instead being relevant to the list size, so if you are having 50 types of columns, you don't see the scroll clearly.

**The following issues are observed AFTER using the ColumnChooser:**

1. If you are adding a column from type "string" (Vs integer, number of enum), the grid will not let you clear the toolbar filter using the X sign on the right of the column.  You will get an error: "(**jquery.jqGrid.min.js:225** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined".
2. The grid behavior post the use of ColumnChooser is out of sync.  Meaning, I can't filter anymore for enumeration values worked before the use of the ColumnChooser, I start to get strange errors on sortings and etc'.  All those strange issues are only starting after I use the ColumnChooser.

I tried to download 4.7.0, 4.7.1, play with the order of the multiselect plugin, nothing helped.  The multiselect I'm using is under the "plugins" directory.

Appreciate any advice here,

Thanks you.

p.s.

I did a small debug to try and isolate the root cause for this bug.  When I overwrite the done function with an empty one, the problem seems to be resolved:

```
done: function(perm) {


}
```

But, when I added the remapColumn function, the problem returned.

```
done: function(perm) {
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);                    
}
```

So might be that the the remapColumns function is the root couse for this?

In regard to the scroller on the right, I think I managed to fix it:

If I replace within the columnChooser function, the line:

```
listHeight = Math.max(multiselectData.selectedList.height(), multiselectData.availableList.height());
```

with those lines:

```
var selectListHeight = Math.max(multiselectData.selectedContainer.height() - multiselectData.selectedActions.outerHeight() - 1, 1);
var availableListHeight = Math.max(multiselectData.availableContainer.height() - multiselectData.availableContainer.outerHeight() - 1, 1);
listHeight = Math.max(selectListHeight, availableListHeight);
```

It fix the issue with the scrolling.

Yet, the biggest issue seems to be the re-order of the columns, which the first symptom is the removal of the filters later on.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle

Comment: Please never use `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` is you report an error. Use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead with exact number of the jqGrid version used (like 4.7.0 instead of "I tried to download 4.7.0, 4.7.1"). The demo which reproduce of described problem is really required. Which version of jQuery and jQuery UI you use? I recommend to try the fixed version of `ui.multiselect.js` (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins)) (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-4-5-4-column-chooser-bug#p31105))?

Comment: Thank you,  I updated jsfiddle with the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/tyanai/ngm5rhgp/

Comment: Here is how to re-create the issue:  1) - click on the Column at the button left to open the columchooser.  You will noticed the scroller is hidden.  Now in order to see the problem when trying to remove a filter, add the column by the name "Description".  Once it is in the grid try to click on the X sign to clean the filter.  Once you do that, you will see the error in the debugger.

Comment: I used version 4.7.1.  When placing the jqGrid src, the error is (jquery.jqGrid.src.js:5794 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of undefined)

Comment: I tried the fixed version of multiselcet but it didn't help.  However, reverting back to jqGrid 4.6.0 solved the scroller issue.  Yet the bigger problem with the removal of the filter column is still happening.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the "remove all" / "add all" links in the top corners do not work predictably / consistently. If you start simply clicking back and forth between the two they will eventually fail. (this is also evident on your jsfiddle posted above) - this happens on MSIE 9, and MSIE 11, but not on Chrome.